# Ionic 2 Dinamic Select, all options selected automatically

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, I have created a select populated with firebase:

```
        <ion-select formControlName="potentialPet">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let potentialPet of potentialPets | async"
               value="potentialPet.name">{{potentialPet.name}}</ion-option>

    </ion-select>
```

On selection I choose one option [choosing one option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNHZP.png), but then all are selected.[options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d4Ol.png)

It seems like a problem related to the ion option value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the value should be binding, so change to

```
<ion-select formControlName="potentialPet">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let potentialPet of potentialPets | async"
               [value]="potentialPet.name">{{potentialPet.name}}</ion-option>

    </ion-select>
```